# How to monitor double click (text selection) on OSX in browser or text editor

Tags: macos, event-handling, textselection, unicorn

Novice programmer asking first question on stack-overflow.  I am writing an app for mac osx that monitors for text selection ie when a user does a double click on some text.  The text can come from a browser or text editor, etc.  The goal is to capture the text and do some processing on the text.

I been reading about the mouse and cursor events in mac library but doesn't seem to answer my questions and googling around leaving me bit lost.
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MouseTrackingEvents/MouseTrackingEvents.html

Anyone guru want to share where I can find the answer?  Any guidance will be appreciated! :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't monitor from an app what the user is doing with some other app. If you want to provide something which manipulates  selected texts in other apps, use [System Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000850-97598). All you have to do is to provide the function which consumes the selected texts; OS X automatically does all the monitoring, passing of the selected text to your app etc.

Starting with 10.6, system services also appear in the context menu.